# encrypt decrypt a file: SVG or XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, svg, encryption

I use these two functions to encrypt / decrypt files :

```
    private function encrypt_file($source,$destination,$passphrase,$stream=NULL) {
    // $source can be a local file...
    if($stream) {
        $contents = $source;
        // OR $source can be a stream if the third argument ($stream flag) exists.
    }else{
        $handle = fopen($source, "rb");
        $contents = @fread($handle, filesize($source));
        fclose($handle);
    }

    $iv = substr(md5("\x1B\x3C\x58".$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
    $key = substr(md5("\x2D\xFC\xD8".$passphrase, true) . md5("\x2D\xFC\xD9".$passphrase, true), 0, 24);
    $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);
    $fp = fopen($destination, 'wb') or die("Could not open file for writing.");
    stream_filter_append($fp, 'mcrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $opts);
    fwrite($fp, $contents) or die("Could not write to file.");
    fclose($fp);

}


private function decrypt_file($file,$passphrase) {

    $iv = substr(md5("\x1B\x3C\x58".$passphrase, true), 0, 8);
    $key = substr(md5("\x2D\xFC\xD8".$passphrase, true) .
            md5("\x2D\xFC\xD9".$passphrase, true), 0, 24);
    $opts = array('iv'=>$iv, 'key'=>$key);
    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
    stream_filter_append($fp, 'mdecrypt.tripledes', STREAM_FILTER_READ, $opts);

    return $fp;
}
```

It works perfectly for most files. But there is a problem with SVG or XML files in general. Decryption of an SVG file for example gives characters "NUL NUL ..." in the last line. As you can see in this picture:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to read and write to files (and what flags)?

Comment: I apologize. I did not give the right function. I have to modify my question but I can not edit it.

Comment: Encryption filters are deprecated in new PHP versions: https://secure.php.net/manual/de/filters.encryption.php

Comment: from [example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.encryption.php), `$data = rtrim(stream_get_contents($fp));//trims off null padding`

Comment: Thank you @James that was the problem. Now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have copied the code straight from the [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/filters.encryption.php). But: As it says on the same page, there are several issues with this code. Basically using `md5` for key derivation is far from optimal. See http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059608390/php-documentation-woes for full description. This and encryption filters are deprecated (see same link), I would recommend abandoning this style of cryptography.

**I would also recommend using some tested PHP crypto library like [libsodium-php](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php).** This will also be integrated into php7 itself. ([Source](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/libsodium))

Back to topic: What you are seeing is the encryption padding. For the block cipher (in your case DES) to work, each chunk has to have the size given by the algorithm. Since most data doesn't care about chunk size, the algorithm has to apply some kind of padding.

When decrypting, you also receive the padded value. To get to your output value, you need to remove the padding afterwards. In your case this would be to trim the tailing `NUL` charachters. Its already in the documentation (thanks to [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james) for pointing this out)

```
$data = rtrim(stream_get_contents($fp)); //trims off null padding
```